# Laravel pluck() method not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a cms type of application. For that while inserting users for their roles i.e.Administrator, Subscriber and Author, I am using pluck() method to retrieve data from roles table and display role in select dropdown as array but the problem is it is not working as it says [htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given] Please help me how can i fix this or are there are any other methods that can be used instead of pluck?.

AdminPostsController:

```
public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();

    return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
}
```

Create Page(create.blade.php):

```
<div class = "form-group">
{!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
{!! Form::text('role_id', array(''=>'Choose Your Role')+$roles, null, 
['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: `Form::text`? Don't you mean `Form::select` ?

Comment: For drop-down list there's `Form::select`

Comment: Hahha LOL! My mistake. Thanks for showing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem isn't on `pluck` method, but on your blade view:

```
<div class = "form-group">
{!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
{!! Form::text('role_id', array(''=>'Choose Your Role')+$roles, null, 
['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

`Form::text` method expects a string as 2nd parameter, you gave an array.

Use `Form::select` instead if you want a select.

Comment: Thx a lot bro. ANSWERED!

Answer (score 1):

AdminController should looks like:

```
public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

    return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
}
```

And use blade Forms like below:

```
{!! Form::select('role_id', [null => 'Choose your role'] + $roles, null,
 ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

You can use default value too by passing something to the 3rd position at Form::select(). Eg.

```
{!! Form::select('INPUT_NAME', ['your' => 'array', 'with' => 'options], DEFAULT_VALUE, ['class' => 'example class',]]) !!}
```

[Laravel Collective documentation.](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists)